# Creating a kind of class in C

Tags: c, class, gcc, header

I'm trying to implement some sort of "classes" in C.

My code currently consists of these 3 files:

- SampleClass.c
- SampleHeader.h
- test.c

SampleHeader.h:

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_CLASS_H
#define SAMPLE_CLASS_H

struct Sample {
    int i, j;
};

extern const struct SampleClass {
    struct Sample (*new)(int i, int j);
} Sample;

#endif
```

SampleClass.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "SampleHeader.h"

static struct Sample new (int i, int j) {
    return (struct Sample) {
        .i = i, .j = j
    };

    const struct SampleClass Sample = {
        .new = &new
    };
}
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "SampleHeader.h"

int main (void) {
    struct Sample classInC = Sample.new(3, -4);

    return 0;
}
```

Shamelessly ripped from [REDACTED].

The problem is that at compile time (`gcc -o app test.c SampleClass.c`) it fails with:

```
In function 'main':
undefined reference to 'Sample'
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your function `new` contains a definition of a local, Sample, initialized after returning from the function. Whatever it is you expect that to do, it isn't doing it. Note how the link differs.

Comment: Would you mind checking the site for me? As I nearly copied the code with the "Complex.h" "Complex.c" "Complex_test.c" and tell me what the difference is and why his code works for him and mine doesn't?

Comment: See the two answers below, both of which point out the lack of copying. If you are familiar with C, you should understand why your code is wrong. If you aren't you should learn it before attempting this sort of thing.

Comment: I see my mistake. Now I actually realize what kind of a stupid mistake I made. I actually feel like I have wasted all of you guys' time with this question. Indeed I know the mistake, could have noticed it myself and fixed it but I'm so tired that I make this kinds of stupid mistakes. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Don't worry about it ... it's refreshing to have someone take responsibility like that, and it means you'll be a great SO participant in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't follow the pattern from your link.

```
static struct Sample new (int i, int j) {
    return (struct Sample) {
        .i = i, .j = j
    };

    const struct SampleClass Sample = {
        .new = &new
    };
}
```

should be

```
static struct Sample new (int i, int j) {
    return (struct Sample) {
        .i = i, .j = j
    };
}

const struct SampleClass Sample = {
    .new = &new
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm really stupid for not noticing this one... I feel like I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your SampleClass.c shall probably contain:

```
static struct Sample new (int i, int j) {
    return (struct Sample) {
        .i = i, .j = j
    };
}

const struct SampleClass Sample = {
    .new = &new
};
```

Comment: You helped me greatly with your response. I see my error and I wonder why I didn't notice it myself.